# Is there a param to adjust the bar a little bit with specified position in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting a histogram using plt.bar function.

```
arr = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 3]
hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(arr, bins = range(7))
plt.bar(bin_edges[:-1], hist)
plt.xlim(min(bin_edges), max(bin_edges))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Each bar is right at the middle of a tick (1, 2, ... , 5), which does not indicate the edges clearly including left side, excluding right side, except last edge.

param width is used to set width of bar, not position.

Is there a param to put each bar a little bit right with specified position (such as 0.5) in matplotlib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three options. You may choose whichever you find most suitable and easy to comprehend.

**Option 1**: Shift the bar centers (x-positions) by 0.5 to left (-0.5) or right (+0.5) and then set x-ticks at 0.5, 1.5, 2.5 and so on

```
arr = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 3]
hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(arr, bins = range(7))
plt.bar(bin_edges[:-1]-0.5, hist)
plt.xlim(min(bin_edges), max(bin_edges))
plt.ticks(bin_edges[:-1]-0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Option 2**: Use `align=edge` which will by default align to the right of the ticks and assume some default thickness (looks like 0.8 in the below figure)

```
plt.bar(bin_edges[:-1], hist, align='edge')
```

[image]

**Option 3**: Use `align=edge` with a defined width (positive width will align to the right, negative width will align to the left)

```
plt.bar(bin_edges[:-1], hist, align='edge', width=-0.5)
```

[image]